# Facebook hidden post issue with graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I send a request with `is_hidden` (to hide a post), I get an error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Cannot hide/unhide story posted by page itself",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "FJk5AKOr+mU"
  }
}
```

And when I send request with `timeline_visibility` hidden, then "Facebook posts" is showing hidden by post id, but still showing on Facebook page. How can I hide the Facebook posts?

Comment: Apps can only update posts that where created via that same app in the first place.

Comment: then @CBroe how can i hide the post using graph api from facebook page

Comment: is it possbile to hide the facebook post from facebook page using graph api

Comment: we have send page access token and user access token with is_hidden=true after post published but get the error when send is_hidden and not is_hidden on facebook page. and when request send with timeline_visibility and get response true but not any changes made on facebook page and visible by other user but post showing hidden.